# Why have my offline maps suddenly stopped working?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid v6.0.1 to display some 4uMaps tiles generated using MOBAC.  I had this all working until I tried to add a Mylocation overlay.  Since then, in spite of reverting (I thought) to my original code, offline maps will not work although using the TileFactory.MAPNIK does.  When using offline maps all I get is the dreaded grey screen.  I've checked my permissions and confirmed that (a) my app can read the 4uMaps.zip file and that it contains a folder called 4uMaps and (b) I am setting the map centre to a point within the map area.

My manifest file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.corunna.osm">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/evcharger1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/evcharger1"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My code is:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MapView map = null;
ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
Context ctx;
IMapController mapController;

/** Base path for osmdroid files. Zip files are in this folder. */
public static File OSMDROID_PATH = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"osmdroid");

/** Base path for tiles. */
public static File TILE_PATH_BASE = new File(OSMDROID_PATH, "tiles");

/** 600 Mb */
public static long TILE_MAX_CACHE_SIZE_BYTES = 600L * 1024 * 1024;

/** 500 Mb */
public static long TILE_TRIM_CACHE_SIZE_BYTES = 500L * 1024 * 1024;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**************************************************************************
     *          Get Context and OSM User Agent
     **************************************************************************/

    ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

    /**************************************************************************
     *          Check Permissions
     **************************************************************************/

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }
    else {
        Log.e("OSMCH","Read External Storage allowed");

    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
    else {
        Log.e("OSMCH","Write External Storage allowed");

    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 3);
    }
    else {
        Log.e("OSMCH","Coarse Location allowed");

    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 4);
    }
    else {
        Log.e("OSMCH","Fine Location allowed");

    }

    /**************************************************************************
     *          Initialise maps
     **************************************************************************/

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    File umaps = new File(OSMDROID_PATH,"4uMaps.zip");
    Log.e("OSMCH","4uMaps read status = " + umaps.canRead());

    map.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the network and test your zip loading.
    map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("4uMaps", 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[]{"http://tileserver.4umaps.eu/"}));
   //map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(8);
    mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(54.280009, -2.103238));

    /**************************************************************************
     *      Allow Rotational Gestures so that user can more easily view route
     **************************************************************************/

    RotationGestureOverlay mRotationGestureOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(ctx, map);
    mRotationGestureOverlay.setEnabled(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    map.getOverlays().add(mRotationGestureOverlay);
 }
}
```

The log results are:-

```
2019-08-02 22:21:39.991 17401-17401/com.corunna.osm E/OSMCH: Read External 
Storage allowed
2019-08-02 22:21:39.992 17401-17401/com.corunna.osm E/OSMCH: Write External 
Storage allowed
2019-08-02 22:21:39.993 17401-17401/com.corunna.osm E/OSMCH: Coarse Location 
allowed
2019-08-02 22:21:39.994 17401-17401/com.corunna.osm E/OSMCH: Fine Location 
allowed
2019-08-02 22:21:40.093 17401-17401/com.corunna.osm E/OSMCH: 4uMaps read 
status = true
```

I have a directory stucture of /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles set up with 4uMaps.zip in /sdcard/osmdroid.  As far as I can tell (I wrote a small file to it) /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles is writable.

Finally, my build.gradle file (unchanged) is:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.corunna.osm"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
   optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
}
```

I suspect that the problem is something to do with my Manifest file as it all went wrong when I added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION but I've tried removing that to no effect.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?  I should emphasise that it was working and now it is not and I cannot figure out what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the default osmdroid source and tile directories are not as implied in the documentation.  Both of these need to be explicitely set using:-

```
    Configuration.getInstance().setOsmdroidBasePath(OSMDROID_PATH);
    Configuration.getInstance().setOsmdroidTileCache(TILE_PATH_BASE);
```

as part of the initial configuration, ie right at the top of the app.